# Creating Sums & Grand Totals (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a table called "Payments". In this table I pretty much want to show at the end the grand totals for debit, credit, and the balance between the debit & credit.  Also, rather than have a  negative (-) amount for certain balances I  want it to show as 0. I was suggested to use a view but I'm still in the process of understanding the whole concept (newbie to SQL).I'm using Oracle. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE Payments
(
 DRECNO    NUMBER,
 DNUMBER   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DTYPE     VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
 DCHECKNO  NUMBER,
 DDEBIT    NUMBER,
 DCREDIT   NUMBER,
 DDATE     DATE,
 COMMENTS  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
```

Example of a record in the table

```
Record#   CDNumber   Type    Check #      Debit     Credit     Date       Comments
13997      4390        GG      0           98        0                  COURT COST
13763      4390        CC      0          908        0                   DEMO COST
19001      4390        LV    8732          0        26      05-MAY-99
```

Comment: You could post an example of your desired result

Comment: Are you writing this query to be used in a report? Have you considered using a reporting tool like Microsoft SSRS or Crystal Reports to do this? You can do aggregations in SQL, but it will involve some hokery to get it to show up at the bottom of the table.